# Closing STDIN for a Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, cpu-usage

I am working on a project that has multiple C++ executables that communicate using named pipes.  The main application (App1) spawns the rest of the applications.  When spawning, it closes `STDIN` for the children using:

```
close(STDIN_FILENO);
```

And it redirects `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to other files that are specific to the child processes.  This makes it so that the output from App1 is *only* from App1 and none of the children.  It also allows App1 to accept input from `STDIN` and not let it get captured by the child processes.

One of the child processes is a Qt application.  When spawned, it is using as much CPU as it can, slowing my computer considerably.  If I do not close `STDIN` for the child processes, this behavior stops (but the children capture `STDIN` instead of the main process, which I don't want).

Why does this happen and how can I prevent the Qt applications from using all the CPU cycles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what the issue was while fixing another issue I was having.  I was closing the `STDIN` file descriptor before redirecting the `STDERR` and `STDOUT` file descriptors.  This was messing up the indexes that are used when I used `freopen()` to redirect them.

I moved the `close()` of `STDIN` to after the redirection, and don't seem to have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give the Qt app what it wants? Use `dup2` after `fork` but before `exec`? `dup2` will replace a given file descriptor with another so you can replace stdin with a file. Quick example:

```
if(fork() == 0)
{
   int somefd = open("somefile", O_RDONLY);
   // replace stdin (0) with somefd before exec-ing
   if(dup2(somefd, 0) == -1)
   {
      // cunning plan failed
   }
   // exec Qt app here
}
```